# Как сохранить правила ipfw в файл?

Tags: firewall, freebsd

Здравствуйте.

Хочу сохранить все правила ipfw в файл. А затем, эти правила загрузить на другом сервере из этого файла.
Подскажите пожалуйста как можно это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

```
ipfw show > firewall.sh
```

Потом ручками удаляете первые три столбца и добавляете вначале каждой строки

```
ipfw add
```

Не забываем про **ipfw table** и **ipfw nat**. Но лучше обратиться к скрипту загрузки правил **/etc/rc.firewall**. А также обратите внимание на опцию **firewall_script** в скрипте **/etc/rc.conf**